# nltk can't using ImportError: cannot import name compat

Tags: python, twitter, nltk

This is my code

```
import nltk
freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
print freq_dist.keys()[:50] # 50 most frequent tokens
print freq_dist.keys()[-50:] # 50 least frequent tokens
```

And I am getting this error message:

> ImportError: cannot import name compat

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn9XA.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CvjO.jpg)

Comment: Try: `pip install -U nltk`

Comment: if your NLTK broken, alvas comment works for me,,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912501/unable-to-install-nltk-using-pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to import the entirety of nltk when you probably only need a small portion. try editing your code to

```
from nltk import FreqDist
freq_dist = FreqDist(words)
print freq_dist.keys()[:50] # 50 most frequent tokens
print freq_dist.keys()[-50:] # 50 least frequent tokens
```