# When I try to import TextBlob I get "ImportError: cannot import name compat". What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, importerror, textblob

From what I can tell "compat" is some component of NLTK, TextBlob is built on. Strangely, I've imported TextBlob in the past, so this must be something recent. I've updated both TextBlob and NLTK to their most recent versions, so that's not what the problem is.

Similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100967/nltk-cant-using-importerror-cannot-import-name-compat) remain basically unresolved, since the recommendation is basically "don't import all of NLTK".

Edit: My code is as follows

`from textblob import TextBlob`

Comment: show the entire traceback please.

Comment: Try: `pip install -U nltk`

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure textblob is installed correctly? You might want to try

```
pip install -U textblob
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Try running the code afterwards, it should work correctly.