# Unable to install nltk using pip

Tags: python, nltk

Hi I am unable to install nltk. I have already install Python.

C:\Users>pip install nltk

Downloading/unpacking nltk
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement nltk
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for nltk
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\pinnapav\pip\pip.log

Comment: Try to use this command: `py -m pip install --upgrade nltk`

Comment: Thanks It worked. I am unable mark your question as nswered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use the command `py -m pip install --upgrade nltk`! This worked on my computer, with the same, basic Python-Installation.

Now you can mark as Answered ^-^

Answer (score 4):

Try to update pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade nltk
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pip install --upgrade nltk
```

Sometimes it still throws the error for SSL if you use:

```
py -m pip install --upgrade nltk
```